# How are segwit block transactions verified?

Tags: segregated-witness

From my understanding, segwit blocks send transaction information without the witness, which includes the signature. I thought nodes needed the signature to verify the transactions?

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct.

All segwit blocks do differently is having the witnesses (which include the signature) in a separately-hashed area. They're still an integral part of the block, and full validation cannot proceed without the witness data. Removing or altering the witness data will invalidate a block.

What this does permit is stripping the witness data without affecting validity **according to pre-segwit validation rules**. This is the basis for using segwit as a blocksize increase (the old 1 MB block size limit thus only applies to the non-witness part, as old nodes don't see the witness data). However, nodes that implement the segwit rules need the full witness.

Comment: Can you please explain what a non-segwit node sees when a segwit node notifies it of a new block, vs what a non-segwit node would see from a non-segwit node? I think I'm having trouble understanding how the witness data can be stripped and still be seen as valid

Comment: There is no difference. Non-witness nodes are never sent the witness data. Witness nodes strip it before sending it to them.

Comment: So they strip the portion of their block that contains witness data, correct? If this is true, then the non-witness node doesn't receive the witness data (which includes the signature). If so, how do non-witness nodes verify the block?

Comment: Yes. To them, the block is valid without witnesses. Every script that requires a witness looks like one that is always true to non-witness nodes.

Comment: So do non-witness nodes just accept blocks at face value from witness nodes? They don't need to validate it at all?

Comment: They validate everything they care about. That does not include the validation of witness spends, as those look like anyonecanspend to them. But non-segwit scripts are still validated, PoW is validated, inflation is checked, UTXOs must exist, ...